# Connecting to Oracle via Python (Spyder IDE)

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I am having difficulty connecting Oracle via python (in Spyder).

I am trying to import cx_Oracle , and get an error (No module named cx_Oracle)

I have Python 3.7.0 installed
I have downloaded cx_Oracle 7.0.0 and installed via a command line "pip install"
I have downloaded oracle instantclient_12_2

All are for 64 bit, but I still get the error.

```
import cx_Oracle

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Oracle'
```

Comment: post some code, otherwise we have to just guess

Comment: Check to see if your Spyder Python version aligns to 3.7. It may run at Python 2.7.

Comment: import cx_Oracle

Comment: I uninstalled Anaconda (with Spyder) and uninstalled Python 3.7. I then installed Anaconda with Spyder for Python 2.7, installed Python 2.7, checked my Path environment variables, restarted and tried again. It still failed.